# Count all network requests to a specific host

Tags: tcpdump, netstat

I have a mock server running on my `localhost` that mocks out a back end service that I need for my app.  One thing that I want to do is count the number of requests `[GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,...]` that my app makes to the mock server on my `localhost`.

The server is running on `127.0.0.1:8000`

I think I need to use `tcpdump`, but wondering if `netstat` or some other tool I don't know about is a better fit for this job.